# How to make top ribbon visible on all accounts - My Sites

Tags: my-site, ribbon, css, my-profile

So I've spent a lot of time customizing the look and feel of My Sites using feature stapling but I had been checking the changes using the Administrator account...now I logged in as a test user with minimal permissions and the Top Ribbon dissppears!!!

How can I make the top ribbon be visible for all users no matter the permissions? There doesn't need to be a Site Actions menu available but my entire spacing for the site is based on the ribbon so I would like t visible at all times if possible.

Basically if the ribbon isn't there all content moves up and ruins the look I set up.

Below are two screenshots,one of the Admin account and one of the Regular user account. What can I do to enable the ribbon on the Regular user account?

Thanks for any ideas!!!

**Admin Account:**
[image: Admin Account]

**Regular Account:**
[image: Regular User Account]

I don't think my CSS will matter for this as user accounts don't have the top ribbon visible, this is OOTB. I removed my entire CSS and checked with both a regular user and the admin account and the ribbon is still not visible at the top. Anyways this is my CSS just in case:

```
/* --------------------------body--------------------------- */
body > form > div[id^="s4"] {
  width: 1280px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-width: 0 1px;
}
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
form { 
       width:1280px !important; 
       margin: auto !important; 
}
body.v4master {
       overflow: visible;
       height: inherit;
       width: inherit;
}
body #s4-workspace {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
/* --------------------------ribbon--------------------------- */
body #s4-titlerow {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  position: fixed;
  top: 37px;
  z-index: 22;
}
body #s4-ribbonrow 
{
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
       border-right: 1px solid black;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0px;
  width: 1280px !important;
}
.ribbonbackground, .s4-title {
  background:url('/_layouts/images/header.png') no-repeat scroll 0 transparent !important;
  width: 1280px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
       border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 110px;
} 
.s4-titlelogo { 
  background-image:url('/_layouts/images/logo.png');
  background-position: left center; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 334px;
} 
.s4-titlelogo > a > img { 
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 350px; 
  height: 60px; 
}
/* hide the breadcrumb */
.s4-titletext {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.s4-title h1 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.s4-title h2 {
  font-size: 10px;
}
.s4-pagedescription {
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* --------------------------nav bar--------------------------- */
.ms-globalnav {
  background-color: black !important;
  background: url('/_layouts/images/navigation.png');
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  position: fixed;
  top: 135px;
  width: 1280px !important;
  height: 30px !important;
  z-index: 999;
}
/* font colors */
.s4-sn li.static > a:hover, .s4-sn li.static > a, .ms-contactcardtext1, .ms-newsfeedheader,  .ms-WPBody a, .ms-contactcardtext2, .ms-contactcardtext2 a {
  color: black !important;
}
/* hide hover underline in top bar */
.s4-mysitetn a:hover {
text-decoration: none !important;
}
/* remove the overflow scroll */
.customBodyHolder .customPageWidth {

}
/* change padding and height */
.customBodyHolder {
min-height:200px;
/*padding-bottom: 50px;*/
width: 1280px;
}
/* light blue area at top of profile */
.s4-sn, .ms-profilepageheader {
background-color:#efefef;
}
/* make the site actions colors match the branding */
.ms-siteactionsmenuinner  {
/*background:url("/_layouts/images/bgximg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 -467px #313031;
border-color:#313031;*/
}  
/* main body area */
.s4-ca {
  float: none !important;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  width: 1280px !important;
  position: relative;
  top: 91px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
body #s4-leftpanel {
display:none;
}
body #s4-bodyContainer {
  margin: auto !important;
  width: 1280px !important;
}
/* welcome menu - username and login info */
.s4-trc-container-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  float: right;
  z-index: 1500 !important;
  /*overflow: visible;*/
}
.ms-globalnavtrc s4-trc-container s4-notdlg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1500 !important;
  /*overflow: visible;*/
}
/* help menu */
.ms-globalnavhelp {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Might be helpful to post your ribbon row code.

Comment: What server code are you using to show the ribbon? Is it being wrapped in a permission mask or what? That is more important than the ribbon css.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I have no code for the ribbon, basicaly I just added the CSS and nothing else. The admin ribbon shows up on its own OOTB while the regular user ribbon doesn't. Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this one out...what I did was create a Security Trimmed Control using this code:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="ViewPages">
   <div id="blank-ribbon" class="custom-blank-ribbon">  
   </div>  
</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

*the code goes in the masterpage*

Then I styled the control to look like the top ribbon bar in terms of color and location on the page in my CSS file and I basically got a fake ribbon thats visible for every user. When an admin is logged in the regular ribbon goes right over this fake ribbon so no functionality is lost. Thought I would post my solution in case anyone else encounters this.